# Get an array via function-param

Tags: c++, arrays, void-pointers

I have an array declared as

```
Object array[N];
```

and a function as

```
void GetArray(void** array, size_t count)
{
    *array = array;
    *count = N;
}
```

I'm trying to call the function with this code:

```
size_t number;
GetArray(XXX, &number);
```

where is XXX what should I pass to get the array? Thank you

**EDIT 1**

```
Object *array
GetArray((void**)array, number)
```

**EDIT 2**

```
static Object array[N]
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Copy the values of the array to another array or point the 2 arrays to the same data?

Comment: point the two arrays to the same data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I'm not 100% convinced that I understand your intent correctly,
if `GetArray` has to return `Object array[N]` itself, how about returning
`Object*` from `GetArray`?
For example:

```
size_t const N = 1;
Object array[N];

Object* GetArray(size_t* count)
{
    *count = N;
    return array;
}
```

**EDIT**:
As far as I see your edited question, the argument `number` for `GetArray`
seems to be taken as a reference(not pointer).
So, as for the array too, how about taking a reference instead of a pointer?
Then you can avoid the troublesome `void**` stuff.
For example:

```
void GetArray(Object*& arr, size_t& count)
{
    arr = array;
    count = N;
}

int main() {
    size_t number;
    Object *arr;
    GetArray(arr, number);
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < number; ++ i ) {
        Object o = arr[i]; // example
    }
}
```

Comment: @ise I edited my question with the actual code, it compiles fine but when I compile I have a warning about unitialized variable and the program stop working with a runtime error

Comment: @ise It gives me an error at runtime: arr is unitialized. I edited my question with a thing that could be important

Comment: @Stefano: Strange... I cannot reproduce the problem you mentioned.
Here is [a test on ideone](http://ideone.com/kezUx).

Comment: @ise sorry my fault, I forgot the & after Object* in the function params

Answer (score 0):

Just as with number, you should pass the address of array:

```
GetArray(&array, &number)
```

But with C++, you're better off using reference parameters.

Comment: ok but I didn't understand how I should declare the array variable to pass to the function. Could you explain me?

Answer (score 0):

The array variable is a pointer to the first element of the array (its value is the address of the first element).

```
void GetArray(Object* dest, size_t* count)
{
    dest = source; // source's value is an address; just copy it to dest
    *count = N;
}
...
GetArray(array, &number); // array's value is an address so you don't need "&"
```

Comment: ok but I have a problem: count is the size of the array becuase after calling the GetArray function I need to cycle the array. Now, array how should be declared?

Comment: I mean use this code to loop the array: for (int i = 0; i < (int)number; i++)

Comment: yes I know how to loop the array but I don't understand how I should declare the "array" variable. To declare an array I need the dimension and the dimension is count